Why is Unity triggering a mouse click event when I am only pressing a key on the keyboard?
I am following a tutorial, running Unity version 2022.2.21 <DX11> on Win10, and I am trying to add a button to a UI which can be clicked (mouse), to unpause the game. I am doing this by adding a listener to this button, as follows:
// GamePauseUI:

public class GamePauseUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Button resumeButton;

    private void Awake()
    {
        resumeButton.onClick.AddListener(() =>
        {
            Debug.Log("GamePauseUI > UnpauseGame (click)");
            GameManager.Instance.UnpauseGame();
        });

I am also using the new input system and attached the Pause action to the Escape key, as follows:
// GameInput:

playerInputActions.Player.Pause.performed += Pause_performed; // Escape key

private void Pause_performed(InputAction.CallbackContext obj)
{
    Debug.Log("GameInput > Pause_performed => OnPauseAction");
    OnPauseAction?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

// Game Manager:

private void Start()
{
    GameInput.Instance.OnPauseAction += GameInput_OnPauseAction;
}

// ...

private void GameInput_OnPauseAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // simplified code to illustrate the issue
    Debug.Log("Kitchen > GameInput_OnPauseAction");
    UnpauseGame();
}

Now when the game is running, the following sequence of actions work well (any number of times):

press Esc to Pause -> UI shows
press Esc to Unpause -> UI hides

But when I do this:

press Esc to Pause -> UI shows
click on button to Unpause -> UI hides (ok)
press Esc to Pause -> in addition to correctly triggering the key event, it ALSO triggers the onClick event, causing the Pause UI to only blink and the game to Unpause.

This behavior remains like this unless I click somewhere in the game, which seems to make the system go back to working properly as if I did not click on the button.
So my question is based on this information, is there something obvious I am missing? Why is the onClick event being triggered when I only hit Esc key once?

not sure but I believe to remember that I also had a similar issue once with deactivating an UI element that triggered the current event getting "stuck" - you might try and explicitly force it to loose UI focus calling EventSystem.SetSelectedGameObject(null)

why are you running UnPauseGame at the end of OnPause?

@BugFinder this is not the full method, it is only to show the event handler. In the full method there is a test on a boolean to either pause or unpause. I do not believe there is an error on this logic. There is an issue with events being triggered too many times. There is a volume option in the tutorial, one click = one level up. Since this issue appeared, one click = infinitely looping on volume range (1, 2, 3, ... then 0, 1, 2...). This makes me think there is something stuck as derHugo says.

@derHugo I think there is indeed UI elements deactivated (either in code or already before start, i.e. options window). Where should I place your code? (sorry total Unity noob here)

@derHugo After digging deeper following what you said, it seems I managed to fix it thanks to you (see this link. Thanks a lot! If you post an answer, I'll accept it. Basically solution is to add this in the addListener callback: var eventSystem = FindObjectOfType<EventSystem>(false); eventSystem.SetSelectedGameObject(null); This removes the selection from the button caused by the previous mouse click. Somehow when UI shows, selected button triggers a click (?!)

Still not 100% ok because now Fire1 and Submit are being issued. If I manage to fix this I'll post the result here as well.

@evilmandarine it is still weird that these would be triggered by pressing ESC .. I would expect it by pressing RETURN which is the default submit event

@derHugo This is probably because I defined Escape  as an Input Action in the new input system, for "Pause". The issue I have now is that onClick triggers twice. The comment in Button.cs (external file) says "Note: Triggered on MouseUp after MouseDown on the same object." but it also triggers on MouseDown for me. I am trying to figure out how to use OnPointerClick. Also I am using UI -> Button - TextMeshPro, not sure if this changes sth.

When I click on the button (down), then move the cursor out and release, only one click is performed (only one event is triggered).

@derHugo Ok, fixed it. This issue was because I was using the new input system but with the old one linked to the Event System (Unity issues a "red flag" warning under Event System Inspector). I changed to the new one inEvent System -> Input System UI Input Module. There the left click is linked to "UI / Click". With this setup, both keyboard and mouse seem to work. Thanks again!
